# PHP - Parsing xml with accents

Tags: php, xml-parsing, non-ascii-characters

I'm trying to parse an xml file that contains accents, but I get this error "String could not be parsed as XML".
Unfortunately I can't work on the xml file, as it is downloaded from an external source, so I was wondering if there's any easy way to fix it.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$requestAddress = "test.xml";

// Gets data
$xml_str = file_get_contents($requestAddress,0);

// Parses XML
$xml = new SimplexmlElement($xml_str);
?>
```

I have looked all around but I can't see any solution to the problem, or at least I don't understand them! :-)

Comment: What is the encoding of the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that `file_get_contents()` does not take into account the encoding of the file. Your accents might be considered as invalid characters and break the XML structure.

Use [`mb_detect_encoding()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) to detect the encoding.

Use [`utf8_encode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) to convert your characters to UTF-8.

Comment: You were right! Thank's sooooooo much! Now everything works just fine, no matter how many accents!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure the encoding agrees with the header of the document (usually utf-8).

If the encoding (charset) does not match, you can load the file as a generic text file and then convert the character encoding with the *iconv()* function to the correct one.